# Access Form Dlookup - Using a Combo box for the expression value

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Good Morning,

I am doing some work for a colleague and he wants a form creating where he can change to column that is looked at through a combo box as well as the criteria

I have tried the following

```
=DLookUp(" & [Combo8] & ","Product Guidelines","PC =  '" & [Combo2] & "'")
```

but get an error, if i hard code the expression to one of the columns it works fine but when it's set to look at the combo box it doesn't work, I have tried several variants of the code but have no ran out of ideas

Please can someone help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at your code. You are passing the literal string `" & [Combo8] & "` (including spaces and ampersands) as first parameter to `DLookup`.

Try

```
=DLookUp([Combo8], "Product Guidelines", "PC = '" & [Combo2] & "'")
```

or if the content of `Combo8` has spaces,

```
=DLookUp("[" & [Combo8] & "]", "Product Guidelines", "PC = '" & [Combo2] & "'")
```

or maybe even with quotes around it:

```
=DLookUp("""[" & [Combo8] & "]""", "Product Guidelines", "PC = '" & [Combo2] & "'")
```

Comment: Hi Andre,Thank you, I have tried this but still get #Error. I believe it may be to do with how he has the column heading set up, they are Jan 18, Feb 18 etc etc

Comment: Sorry that was my fault pressing enter to go to the next line not realizing it would post the comment haha. Do you think the column headers would cause the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax would be:

```
=DLookUp("[FieldNameToLookUp]","[Product Guidelines]","PC = '" & Me![Combo2] & "'")
```

as you probably don't have a field named Combo8.

If Combo8 holds that name, it would be:

```
=DLookUp("[" & Me!Combo8 & "]","[Product Guidelines]","PC = '" & Me![Combo2] & "'")
```